Does every position of the Red-Green-Blue Hackenbush game form the proper class of games?
Note: Here, by the class of games, I mean the non-loopy, normal-play combinatorial games as defined in Aaron Siegel's Combinatorial Game Theory.
From On Numbers and Games and Siegel's Combinatorial Game Theory, Red-Blue Hackenbush forms the surreal number class. However, I'm wondering if you can construct a Red-Blue-Green Hackenbush G game from any arbitrary game H in the class of games such that $G = H$ (such that $G$ and $H$ are strictly identical) or $G ≈ H$ (under the equivalence relation of (non-reduced) canonical forms).

I am unsure of the correct word, but I mean that, for every possible game G, is there a red-green-blue Hackenbush position that is identical or equivalent (under the canonical equivalence relationship of games) to G?

What does that have to do with your question about Red-Blue-Green covering Red-Blue? If you had asked the converse, then that would be a significant point, but not for this question.

@PaulSinclair I think the question is clear. LeoDog is asking, given an arbitrary game $G$, does there exist a Red-Blue-Green hackenbush position, $H$, such that $G=H$?

@MikeEarnest - If you already knew what he meant by "covering", yes, it is. But alas, not all of us are exposed to every terminology at all times, and thus unfortunately must ask for clarification when a term is used that we have not encountered before. Particularly where the most obvious interpretation has a trivial answer. Then upon learning that indeed this was the intent, I am left wondering what is the misunderstanding that has caused LeoDog to not realize the obvious answer. The reply now makes me suspect they have confused which game is covering  and which is covered.

Yes, I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I do mean what Mike Earnest said in his comment. I'll edit my question to clarify that intent.

No, most games do not have an equivalent Hackenbush position. Any Hackenbush position is equal to a number plus an infinitesimal. In particular, the temperature of such a game is always zero or negative. Any hot game, like $\pm1=\{1\mid -1\}$, does not appear in the class of Hackenbush positions.
The following theorem is given in Winning Ways vol 1, in the chapter titled "Hackenbush". Given a Hackenbush position, define its purple mountain to be the set of red/blue edges which are connected to the ground via a sequence of red/blue edges. Imagine deleting all edges in the purple mountain, and then merging all vertices in the purple mountain into the ground. This new position is called the green jungle of the original position. In the green jungle, every edge touching the ground is green, but there still can be red/blue edges which are suspended above the ground.

Theorem: Let $H$ be a Hackenbush position. Let $M$ be the purple mountain of $H$, and let $J$ be the green jungle of $H$. Then $H=M+J$.

Since $M$ is a red-blue Hackenbush position, $M$ is a number. The position $J$ is dicotic (both players have a move from every nonterminal position, as defined by Siegel), which means $J$ is an infinitesimal. Thus, my claim at the beginning is proved.

Thanks! I completely forgot that Hackenbush is a cold game, implying that hot games do not have an equivalent Hackenbush position.
